# New Google Now and Google+ card interface

Tags: android, android-layout, google-plus, google-now

Google Now and Google+ (Android) both make use of a card-like interface.

[image]

I was wondering if anyone had any idea how this interface can be replicated on Android.

They both have quite interesting animations for displaying new cards too; any thoughts would be great.

Comment: Just to clarify - it's more the look and feel of the card view I'm after. Essentially I need it to behave like a ListView i.e. I can populate the screen with cards dynamically but I'd like each row of the list to look like a card. If there's another layout I could adapt instead, that would be great

Comment: After studying video on youtube, I thinks it s something like a listview with two views, one for the closed cards, and one for the open one. There is also the animation between the two views... I don't think we sould need to reinvent all the API to obtain a similar result.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I have posted a tutorial on how to replicate / create Google Cards style layout [here](http://shardulprabhu.blogspot.in/2012/09/google-now-cards-layout.html).

Key steps

1. Create a custom layout
2. Add observer for drawing children
3. Animate alternating cards

Heres a code snippet

```
@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

    final int heightPx = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

    boolean inversed = false;
    final int childCount = getChildCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);

        int[] location = new int[2];

        child.getLocationOnScreen(location);

        if (location[1] > heightPx) {
            break;
        }

        if (!inversed) {
            child.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),
                    R.anim.slide_up_left));
        } else {
            child.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),
                    R.anim.slide_up_right));
        }

        inversed = !inversed;
    }

}
```

Comment: Good One! Think the below links would be helpful.

https://github.com/nadavfima/cardsui-for-android
http://nhaarman.github.io/ListViewAnimations/

Comment: @Sharddul I need to put views dynamically into <com.shardul.nowlayout.NowLayout> </---> . Instead of those textviews in tutorial. How to achieve that? I tried addView(view), but :(

Comment: Can you attach the animation code too for, slide_up_right?

Answer (score 21):

Take a look at http://ryanharter.com/blog/2013/01/31/how-to-make-an-android-card-list/

Copy of the example:

/res/drawable/bg_card.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"
            android:dither="true">

            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>

            <solid android:color="#ccc" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"
            android:dither="true">

            <corners android:radius="2dp" />

            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

            <padding android:bottom="8dp"
                android:left="8dp"
                android:right="8dp"
                android:top="8dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Use it as the background of your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="12dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_card">

        <!-- Card Contents go here -->

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: You may need to add padding field to the first rect-item.

Answer (score 16):

==== Start update 2014-09-29 ====

Use the CardView from the Google Compatibility library (from Android 2.1+):

```
<!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

See https://developer.android.com/preview/material/ui-widgets.html

==== End update ====

(at least) two options:

- https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib
  [image]

or

- https://github.com/afollestad/Cards-UI is a UI library for showing Cards.

See https://github.com/afollestad/Cards-UI/wiki/2.-Intro-Tutorial for an simple introduction.
[image]

Comment: Great work , I hope this is supports all android version afters 11

Comment: Cardslib is awesome but a minsdk of 14 makes it impossible for me. Cardsui also has a min of 15 and it isn't as good IMHO.

Answer (score 10):

I made a very similar Layout you can look at here
https://github.com/Nammari/GooglePlusLayout
 and for a video demo here http://youtu.be/jvfDuJz4fw4
 for the animation that get applied to children , for more details look here
http://nammari.tumblr.com/post/41893669349/goolge-plus-layout
 for a blog post that clarify every thing .

[image]

Comment: Just for curiosity, using this implementation can make scrolling slow in an app that uses large sets of data due to memory usage? It does not recycle views like ListView.

Comment: perhaps you should read the blog post and don't miss the performance tip section... thanks for you comment

Comment: Love it but lack of recycling just makes it a no go for me

Answer (score 7):

The card look and feel shouldn't be hard. You just need a ListView without dividers and your list view items should have a margin.

Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light">

     <TextView
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:paddingTop="16dp"
             android:paddingRight="16dp"
             android:paddingLeft="16dp"
             android:text="Title"
             android:textSize="18dp"
             android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_holo_light"
             />

     <TextView
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:paddingRight="16dp"
             android:paddingLeft="16dp"
             android:text="Subtitle"
             android:textSize="14dp"
             android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_holo_light"
             />

     <ImageView android:layout_marginTop="16dp" 
              android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@drawable/background"/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: According to the comment of the main post, I think it is more about the animation of the cards, and how the list is constructed than the content of the layout.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've been able to replicate the look - now I'd just like to get the overall feel going too!

Answer (score 4):

Have the same need, and have started investigating a bit. 
I've been looking at the apktool output I've been able to get from the com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox apk. (no sources only the res xmls)

This layout (at_place_card.xml) is used for displaying a location. 
It has three text lines and two actions buttons (details and checkin) on the right and an image on the left.

Unfortunately, I am not able to get any style information out from the apk, so the font size, dimensions and colors are just guesses.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:background="@drawable/card_background" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:thegoogle="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:baselineAligned="false" android:layout_weight="1.0">
        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/CardTextBlock">
                <TextView android:id="@id/entry_title" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/CardTitle" />
                <TextView android:id="@id/open_hours" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/CardText" />
                <TextView android:textColor="@color/card_light_text" android:id="@id/known_for_terms" android:paddingBottom="4.0dip" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:maxLines="4" style="@style/CardText" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <ImageButton android:layout_gravity="top|right|center" android:id="@id/card_menu_button" android:layout_width="@dimen/card_action_button_height" android:layout_height="@dimen/card_action_button_height" android:contentDescription="@string/accessibility_menu_button" style="@style/CardMenuButton" />
        </FrameLayout>
        <Space android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0.0dip" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
        <Button android:id="@id/details_button" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/card_action_button_height" android:text="@string/more_details" android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_pin" style="@style/CardActionButtonWithIcon" />
        <Button android:id="@id/checkin_button" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/card_action_button_height" android:text="@string/check_in" android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_check_in" style="@style/CardActionButtonWithIcon" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.velvet.ui.CrossfadingWebImageView android:id="@id/place_photo" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="0.0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:scaleType="centerCrop" android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:baselineAligned="false" android:minHeight="@dimen/at_place_card_content_height" android:layout_weight="1.0" android:contentDescription="@string/at_place_card_image_desc" thegoogle:crossfadeDuration="@integer/image_crossfade_duration" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Update: Was able to get some style information also now. If you're interested here is a zip file with the information I have currently (some resource files from google now).
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4379928/android/googlenow2.zip