# How to make GridView animation like in Google Keep app?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-gridview

### My problem

I am using `GridView` in my application. `GridView` has pretty simple cells: just two `TextView`s. When the user clicks button on the `ActionBar`, a `Dialog` opens. He can make a new cell here. 
I use this code to update my GridView:

```
mNotesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And it works perfectly.
But the new cell just pops up immediately. And the other just changes their position. I want to achieve **animation effect**, which will look like **Google Keep**'s one.

[*> Look **Google Keep** on Google Play Store.*](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.keep)

### My question

Is it possible? Please share some links or some knowledge about it.

I would greatly appreciate for your help. Alex. P.S. Sorry for my English:)

Comment: Somebody! Please help!

Comment: Reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639991/new-google-now-and-google-card-interface SO question maybe can help you.

Comment: @hakanostrom, unfortunately, this is not I want.

Comment: But thx for this link:)

Comment: I am still waiting for some help.

Comment: Were you able to find anything relevant?

Comment: @Saket, unfortunately, no :(

Comment: I managed to implement it perfectly on my own :P

Comment: @Saket, wow! Could you share some code for me, please?:D

Comment: I plan to release a library once my app's development is complete. Do you need it immediately? Because the current code is a complete mess :P

Comment: @Saket can you please share the code of what you've done?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Look into the new RecyclerView released alongside Android L. It is much better than the current Adapter based views and officially supports animations for item re-arrangements.

Comment: @Saket I know. That's why I've asked for a sample that works on pre-"L". I need to use it on an app, but I can't afford it to work only on "L" versions...

Comment: Look into it again mate, it's included in the support library and supports API levels even below 14 (ICS).

Comment: Did anyone find a sample for this? @Saket

Comment: Just use a RecyclerView :) @summers