# Implement Google+ card liked animation via RecylerView

Tags: android, animation

Previously, I implemented Google+ card liked animation ([Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvfDuJz4fw4&feature=youtu.be)), by using technique mentioned in [New Google Now and Google+ card interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639991/new-google-now-and-google-card-interface)

1. Override `LinearLayout`'s `onGlobalLayout` to start animation, so that when activity first launched, we can see the slide up animation of cards.
2. Override `ScrollView`'s `onScrollChanged` to start animation, so that during scrolling, we can see the newly visible cards being animated.

So far, I don't see any technique from `RecylerView`'s example.

I was wondering, without using `LinearLayout` and `ScrollView`, can with achieve the same outcome, by using `RecylerView`? Is there any code example available? (So far, I unable to find one yet)

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines in RecyclerView 's adaptor. Make a Variable for Each card i.e(convertView) here and initialise it.

```
int mLastPosition = 0;
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
 TextView card_head, card_body;
 View convertView;
      @SuppressLint("NewApi")
      public ViewHolder(View v) {
       super(v);
      convertView = v;
    }
 }
```

Bind you view by position

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

// do your thing here

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1) {
        float initialTranslation = (mLastPosition <= position ? 150f
                : -150f);

        holder.convertView.setTranslationY(initialTranslation);
        holder.convertView.animate()
                .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(1.0f))
                .translationY(0f).setDuration(900l).setListener(null);
    }
    // Keep track of the last position we loaded
    mLastPosition = position;
}
```

here , you have to animate the who view it calls onBindViewHolder method when new card is created animate the whole view customize it.